# Using JavaScript and XML in an HTA?

Tags: javascript, xml, hta

JavaScript is the web language I am most comfortable with, and I am new to HTA but I think it might be 'the' way to make a fully local dynamic page (updatable with imgs, forms, and the ability to save/load at runtime) using xml as a data source. I just can't find any info on doing so. Also if you could quickly... can I use image maps in HTA? DHTML is pretty simple for me to wrap my mind around, but throwing strictly client side, xml and HTA into the mix has overwhelmed me. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on CodeProject that will help you: [Browsing XML/XSLT with HTA/Scripting Runtime](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/security/article.php/c10923/)

I am also going to give you my opinion that HTML Applications are *not* the way.  They are completely localized and can't be executed over HTTP.  They've been around since IE 5.0; having said that, if they were "the way", you would not have had andy troubles finding examples :)

Comment: +1 yeah HTAs never really took off in the way MS wanted them to.  Desktop Gadgets are the new HTAs, to a certain extent.